# Converting Words from a Input into Values Python

Tags: python

I am wondering how to convert words from an input into values in Python. The user would enter an input for example:

```
"The dog chased the cat the lion chased the dog"
```

I would then like it to return:

```
["1,2,3,1,4,1,5,6,1,2"]
```

I would like duplicate words to retain the same value as when the word first occurred. I have tried to do this multiple ways, I am using the following code at the moment, but it seems to return random indexes:

```
l = input("Enter a sentence").lower lists= list(l) valueindex = range(len(lists)) print(valueindex)
```

Thanks for the help,
Izaak

Answer (score -1):

```
def text_process(text):
    '''split text to list and all the item are lower case'''

    text_list = text.lower().split()
    return text_list

def lookup_table(text_list):
    '''build dict contain the text and number pair'''

    lookup = {}
    start = 0
    for item in text_list:
        if item not in lookup:
            lookup[item] = start + 1
            start += 1
    return lookup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = "The dog chased the cat the lion chased the dog"
    text_list = text_process(text)
    lookup_table = lookup_table(text_list)
    out_put = [lookup_table[text]for text in text_list]
    print(out_put)
```

out:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: I must admit, I'm kind of curious as to how you managed to answer this question 25 minutes after I closed it. I always see a notification instantly.

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate. I checked very carefully. I recommend that you do the same.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 my mistake, thanks for your time.